# Adobe Air iOS app - blank white screen

Tags: air, adobe

We have a fairly large air app, and for some reason, when we package it for iOS, it does not launch correctly. Just a plain white screen. When we launch it in debug mode (or even using Fast packaging), it works fine. Only with the export release build it simply launches a plain white screen and does nothing.

Anybody seen anything similar? Any idea if there is an error of some sort, any way to find out what the error is?

Comment: Are you using an ANE? What version of AIR are you using? What version of iOS? How are you packaging? Do you have proper certificates and mobile provisioning profiles? Can you build a Hello World app under the same settings and certs? We can't diagnose "I have a white screen". You have to give us more information

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, an app that used to compile fine, only works in debug mode or fast packaging. Standard and Release results in a blank white screen.

Answer (score 1):

SO it turns out after hours of struggling with this is the issue was loading swf files. We had some embedded Image assets that were swf files, which works great in debug mode, but fails spectacularly in release mode. Given that the app we are working on is a behemoth that takes over 30 minutes to build a release version (on a very powerful box), this was quite a pain to nail down. We finally converted swfs to fxg and the error went away

Answer (score 0):

I've just experienced a similar white screen issue when building an AIR iOS app (in any mode). The app builds and launches with no errors but just displays a white screen after the launch image has disappeared.

This issue was different to the one above but I want to post this here for future reference.

It turns out that this was due to incorrect read/write permissions on the source files. i.e. I had copied the source files onto another computer and then logged into that computer as a different user.

The solution was to simply re-copy the source files onto the computer whilst logged in as the correct user.